# Reading data from DynamoDB using API Gateway AWS

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

Im trying to set my API Gateway to from DynamoDB but I keep getting this error:

`Endpoint response body before transformations: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request."}`

I tried different Mapping templates but nothing..

My table is called : datasales and has three columns country, region, dep and name. with country is the primary key.

everything is set and when I test results I get an empty json.

can someone tell me how to create the right application/json for this table ?

Comment: Are you using VTL ? Can you show us your code doing the request ?

Comment: { 
    "TableName": "sales",
    "IndexName": "sales-index"
    "KeyConditionExpression": "country = :val",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":val": {
            "S": "$input.params('sales')"
        }
    }
}

Comment: @BTL check my comment above please

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should check the [AWS DynamoDB doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_Amazon_DynamoDB.html).

What do you want to do ? A `query`, a `getItem` ?

Here is the template if you want to get one item :

```
{
    "TableName": "datasales",
    "Key": {
        "country": {
            "S": "$input.params('country')"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html

---

If you want to do a query :

```
{
    "TableName": "datasales",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "country = :c",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":c": { "S": "$input.params('country')" }
    }
}
```

And here is the doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html